# Extract records that DON'T contain values

Tags: sql, database

Presume I have some table with clients details C and some table with Orders Details O
I also have Instant Variable Table that store Special Orders @S

```
DECLARE @S TABLE (Category varchar(250), Item nvarchar(500));
INSERT INTO @S VALUES ('Hardware', 'Hammer'), ('Fruits', 'Apple')
```

How can I join those tables together to pull only records that DON'T contain items declared in special orders table ?
i.e. This means that some records that only contain 'Hammer' should also be extracted if they don't contain 'Apple' and vice versa.

Below Sample Tables:

```
Orders Table 
Order ID CustID     Item_ID Category Item   Qty Total
000505   000001     100101  Fruits   Apple   1  $50.00
000505   000001     100102  Veg      Tomatoes2  $100.00
000505   000001     100103  Veg      Cabbage 1  $50.00
000506   000002     100101  Fruits   Apple   2  $100.00
000506   000002     100106  Hardware Hammer  1  $50.00

Clients Table
CustID  Name    Forename    
000001  Smith   John            
000002  Jones   David
000003  Doe     Joe
```

I'm only Interested in CustID with records where orders don't contain items declared as Special @S hence David would be out of scope since his order contained the items declared as special. John Record should came up since his order 000505 contained only one Special Item which is Apple but missed Hammer So is Joe since he didn't place any orders NULL so he should also be in scope

Expected Result

---

```
CustID  Name    Forname  Item
000001  Smith   John     Apple    
000003  Doe     Joe      NULL
```

Many thanks for help on this

Comment: Add some more sample table data, and also _specify_ the expected result. (A [mcve].) Also add a tag for the dbms you're using, because the above syntax is product specific.

Comment: Updated the answer with table and expected result. Thanks

Comment: Can you please _specify_ the expected result. (Now it's just described.)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

Hey there so if I understand correctly I think a way to solve this would be to create a some arrays for each of the order types and then check if the intersection of the array is equal to the 'special order' array.  I am using Snowflake Dialect so your SQL dialect might mean the array functions have different names.
First CTE is creating an array of the items for each order id.
The special item array is then generated and cross joined so each order has the special array attached.
Second CTE then looks at the intersection of the arrays.
Third and final then checks if the intersection of the array is equal to the original special array, i.e. the special array is completely contained within the order the array and all elements are present.
I'm not clear on what you want after this but changing the final where clause between `=` and `!=` will filter people in / out who have the special order

```
with array_gen AS (
SELECT 
order_id 
, customer_id 
, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT o.Item) as order_content 
, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT s.Item) as special_order_content
FROM orders as o
CROSS JOIN special as s
GROUP BY 1 ,2
    )
, intersect_check AS (
    SELECT 
order_id
, customer_id
, order_content
, special_order_content
, ARRAY_INTERSECTION(special_order_content,order_coNtent ) AS ARRAY_INTERSECT
  FROM array_gen
)

SELECT *
FROM intersect_check
WHERE ARRAY_INTERSECT  = special_order_content
```